# ASP.NET Core 2.0 - Deploy to IIS

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core

Hoping someone has some insight on problems with hosting .NET Core 2.0 apps in IIS

I'm trying to deploy my simple WebAPI project to IIS. Here are the steps I've taken:

- Published to a folder.
- Folder contains web.config
- I start a new website in IIS
- for the physical path, I choose the published folder from step 1 above
- I have AspNetCoreModule installed on my machine. Confirmed this by clicking "Modules" in IIS for this newly created website
- When visiting the URL, I get HTTP  404 errors.

[image]

Given that these steps to deploy to IIS is very different than what I've experienced for other .NET Framework apps I'm used to, I'm not sure why this is failing for me.

Comment: Why are you not using Deploy to IIS? Also, you say "I get HTTP 500" yet your image shows 404. As an FYI: WebAPI does not exist on ASP.NET Core

Comment: Trying to deploy to IIS on my local machine. All resources seem to suggest you should use publish to folder instead of deploy to IIS. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Z1Lg7ssD8I as one example

Comment: Well, they are incorrect. It's always better to use Web Deploy (i.e deploy to IIS). That way you don't have to do it manually and you can even determine which files are changed

Comment: Okay. What do I configure to be my server? What about site name and URL? Is there documentation or tutorials on this? I've only been able to find resources that say use publish to a folder.

Comment: Server = localhost:IISPort, Site name = name of your app on IIS, URL = server. Look [here](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Jun/06/Publishing-and-Running-ASPNET-Core-Applications-with-IIS)

Comment: Web deployment task failed. (Could not connect to the remote computer ("localhost"). On the remote computer, make sure that Web Deploy is installed and that the required process ("Web Deployment Agent Service") is started.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE.)
The requested resource does not exist, or the requested URL is 
Could not connect to the remote computer ("localhost"). On the remote computer, make sure that Web Deploy is installed and that the required process ("Web Deployment Agent Service") is started.

Comment: Web API is doomed to receive 404 when accessed via `/`. Try a web site first please. Web API is meant to be called via other URL patterns.

Comment: @LexLi, for .NET Framework API I deployed locally, it was deployed as an application within a virtual directory. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @LexLi In ASP.NET Core Web API does not exist. The OP may or may not receive a 404 on `/` depending entirely on the routing of every action

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto are you saying that Microsoft does not have Web API in ASP.NET Core? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api

Comment: @LexLi Exactly. Web API was a product in ASP.NET 4.5. In ASP.NET Core, Web API and MVC are a single product. You cannot "use one or the other" because it's a single framework. The fact that you can create REST-oriented Controllers has nothing to do. You could do it in ASP.NET MVC as well

Comment: @SteveBoniface before you fully understand what is Web API, I suggested you to test with a web site project, ASP.NET Core MVC or not, which by default would serve access to `/`. Like this tutorial shows, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api Web API projects are supposed to be accessed using certain URL patterns, and verbs. They are not like web sites.

Comment: @LexLi I just need this web API running in my IIS, don't need a website on IIS. I understand how to deploy a website on IIS, it's pretty easy. What's different about deploying my Web API?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I don't want to waste my time on the naming argument. If someone wants to call it "ASP.NET Core Web API" I don't think that's anything wrong. I just followed the convention this guy is using, and also Microsoft documentation uses similar terms.

Comment: @SteveBoniface There is no difference. What LexLi is saying is that you need to go to a route of a controller/action if you want to get something other than a 404

Comment: @LexLi It's not a naming problem, unfortunately, people believe they are still different products when it's not the case

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto yes, I'm just trying to hit the default endpoint api/values that comes with the project template. (e.g. http://localhost:9999/api/values) No luck. I see a 500 error

Comment: @SteveBoniface Then you need to enable logging (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?tabs=aspnetcore2x) for details) and see what is happening

Comment: Why am I not even seeing the worker process when trying to attach to process? Man, they don't make this easy, do they?

Comment: @LexLi LoggingEvents.GetItem ? What namespace do I need to bring in to use this? I'm not finding this anywhere

Comment: @LexLi I understand web api, I work with it everyday. I should be able to do a simple GET and see content in the browser, and I’m not even trying to POST/PUT, etc

Comment: Can you check the Event Viewer when you get the 500 error? There may be some error event there. You could also add `AddDeveloperExceptionPage` when the environment is Production so that you get a detailed error page instead of the 500 useless page

Comment: gave up trying to host this iis... just doesn't make sense.
HOWEVER, i'm trying to just get by with iis express now, and when trying to test with postman, I see this in postman console: Error: read ECONNRESET.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto didn't even know about Event Viewer until now.. I see a bunch of errors which i assume are relevant. Top error: The Open Procedure for service "WmiApRpl" in DLL "C:\Windows\system32\wbem\wmiaprpl.dll" failed. Performance data for this service will not be available. The first four bytes (DWORD) of the Data section contains the error code.

Answer (score 2):

This should be a comment but i don't have enough reputation.

I had had same issue and I have solved it in following way:

1. Create folder (with application) on this path C:\inetpub\wwwroot
2. On IIS create new web app with physical path on \wwwroot\yourapp

Make sure that you have installed "Internet Information Services Hostable Web Core" (you can add it in Windows Features)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it's not working. Seeing the same 404 error I've shared in my original post

Answer (score 0):

My problem was I needed two extra pieces of software:

1. Windows server hosting (https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/windows)
2. URL Rewrite Module

Comment: I do have the WSH. AspNetCoreModule is visible in the IIS modules for my site. URL rewrite module huh?

Comment: Via WPI Launcher. Search for URL Rewrite https://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx

Comment: Oh okay. Interesting, I’ll read it through and give it a shot. Thanks for sharing @Pim_D !